# How to get the data-id value from iframe tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a button on the page. While clicking, an iframe gets opened. both iframe and button have a different origin. When iframe gets loaded, I need to get the data-id of that iframe from its tag.

I just tried,

```
window.onload = function() {

  var ifr=document.getElementById('iframe_test');
    ifr.onload=function(){
        this.style.display='block';
        console.log($("#iframe_test").data("id"));
    };
}
```

it just returns: `undefined` as an output.

Answer (score 0):

Require:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#iframe_test").load(function(){
        $(this).style.display='block';
        console.log($("#iframe_test").data("id"));
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<iframe id='iframe_test' data-id='ddc' src='http://whatever.com'></iframe>
</body>
```

Chrome console result:

```
ddc
```

Comment: I just loaded a new page in an iframe and included a js file for that page. when I use your solution on that js. I'm still getting **undefined**. can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: I guess you need to check the iframe page, since When I test on local computer, I use a local web page. It works. You can test using a blank local page. Or try to comment line `//$(this).style.display='block';` which might cause error.

Answer (score -1):

By using Javascript, you can do the following using `window.onload`:

```
var iframes= parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
console.log(iframes.getAttribute("data-id"))
```

Below is a demo:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {

                var iframes= parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
                alert(iframes.getAttribute("data-id"))
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id='iframe_test' data-id='foo' src='http://example.com'></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi arora, i just used, $(document).ready( function () {
var token = $(window).attr('data-id');
      alert(token);
}); 
but i still got undefined can you tell where i put mistake?

Comment: @Neela Can you try updated code snippet and let me know if it works for you?